# How to send a base64 image from client to server with react-native and socket.io?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket, socket.io

In a react-native project, im trying to use websockets (socket.io-client/socket.io) to transfer base64 encoded strings from client to server, and then to another client.

what im expecting:

- the base64 image string is sent to server and the server logs "[ Data Received ]"
- the server then emits 'server_send_data' and receiving client listener receives base64 encoded string

what im experiencing:

- base64 encoded image string is successfully encoded
- sending client emits event successfully
- the server then logs '[ Client Disconnected ] ...' instead
- no events are received by receiving client

Server.js io/socket related code:

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
console.log('\n[ Connected To Client ]\n', socket.id)

  initRoom(socket)

  handleReceivedData(socket)

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('\n[ Client Disconnected ]\n', connectedAccounts)
    delete connectedAccounts
  })

  socket.on('client_send_data', e => {
    console.log(socket.id, 'sent', e)

    socket.to(e.account_id).emit('server_send_data', e.data)
  })
});


const initRoom = socket => {
  socket.emit('server_join_room')

  socket.on('client_join_room', accountId => {
    if (connectedAccounts.hasOwnProperty(accountId)) {
      const socketIds = connectedAccounts[accountId]['socket_ids']
      socketIds.push(socket.id)
    } else {
      connectedAccounts[accountId] = {
        inProgress: true,
        socket_ids: [socket.id]
      }
    }

    socket.join(accountId)
  })
}

const handleReceivedData = socket => {
  socket.on('admin_data_send', e => {
    console.log('[ Data Received ]')
    const { account_id, data } = e

    io.to(account_id).emit('display_data_send', data)
  })
}
```

Photo Picker (sender):

```
export default Photo = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [photoURI, onPhotoURI] = useState('')

  const openPicker = () => {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      cropping: false,
      includeBase64: true
    })
      .then(async image => {
        onPhotoURI(image.data)
        console.log('[ photo ]:', image)
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('some_key')
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('some_key', String(image.data))
      })
      .catch(e => alert(e))
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'gray' }}>
      <Text>Photo Data Stored: {photoURI !== '' ? 'True' : 'False'}</Text>
      <Pressable onPress={openPicker}>
        <Text>Take Picture</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
sendPic = async () => {
  console.log('[ Attempting to send Data to server ]')
  this.test.emit('admin_data_send', {
    account_id: ACCOUNT_ID,
    data: this.state.photoURI
  })
}
```

Home (client)

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      socketId: '',
      photoBase64: '',
      readyForSync: false,
      displayData: null
    }
    this.test = null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initSocket()
  }

  async componentDidUpdate() {
    try {
      const stored = await AsyncStorage.getItem('some_key')
      this.setState({ photoBase64: stored })
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e)
    }
  }

  initSocket = async () => {
    const endpoint = await isEmulator() ? emulator_socket : socket
    this.test = io(endpoint)
    
    this.test.on("connect", async () => {
      console.log(`${await isEmulator() ? '[ Emulator Connected ]' : '[ Physical Connected ]'}`, 'Endpoint:', endpoint, 'Id:', this.test.id)
      this.setState({ socketId: this.test.id })
    });

    this.test.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log('[ disconnected ]', this.test.id); // undefined
    });

    this.test.on('server_join_room', () => {
      this.test.emit('client_join_room', ACCOUNT_ID)
    })

    this.test.on('display_data_send', e => {
      console.log('[ Display Data Recevied From Server ]')
      this.setState({ displayData: e })
    })
  }

  sync = async () => {
    this.setState({ readyForSync: true })
    console.log('[ Sync Started ]')

    this.test.emit('display_ready', {account_id: ACCOUNT_ID})
  }

  sendPic = async () => {
    const endpoint = await isEmulator() ? emulator_socket : socket
    console.log('[ Attempting to send Data to server ]')

    // divide base64 into 3 segments
    console.log('[ base64 length ]:', this.state.photoURI.length)
    // loop the emit
    this.test.emit('admin_data_send', {
      account_id: ACCOUNT_ID,
      data: this.state.photoBase64
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#d1d1d1' }}>
        {this.state.readyForSync ? (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color="#333" size="large" />
            <Text>Awaiting Data From Admin Device...</Text>
            {
              this.state.displayData !== null && (
                <View style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}>
                  <Image src={{ uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.displayData}` }} />
                </View>
              )
            }
          </View>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 20 }}>{Platform.isTV ? 'TV App' : Platform.OS}</Text>

            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 20 }}>Socket ID: {this.state.socketId}</Text>

            <Pressable style={styles.press} onPress={this.sync}>
              <Text> SYNC APP </Text>
            </Pressable>

            <Pressable style={styles.press} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Photo')}>
              <Text> TAKE PIC </Text>
            </Pressable>

            <Pressable style={styles.press} onPress={this.sendPic}>
              <Text> SEND PIC </Text>
              <Text>{this.state.photoBase64}</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </>
        )}
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}
```

How can i make sure the connection isnt lost and the data is received by the server and successfully transmitted back to receiving client?

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), plz. There is nothing about how your client's code is used.

Comment: @x00 updated for ya

Comment: It could be for a lot of different reasons. Right now we are not sure if it's an issue with the client or the server. To ensure it's something on the client (mobile app), try to first use a tool to convert small and large size images to base64 (https://www.base64-image.de) and then send it to the server using a tool like Postman. If that is successful then just increase your timeout `socket.heartbeatTimeout = 30000;`, or else its an issue with the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm suspecting [maxHttpBufferSize](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#maxhttpbuffersize), since the default value is only 1 MB (`1e6`). Your base64 encoded image likely causes the message to go over this limit, which according to the documentation, will close the socket.

In your initialization of `io`, it might help to specify

```
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  maxHttpBufferSize: 1e8 // 100 MB
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try to send string as packets and recollect them at your frontend side. This way you'll be able to send large files too without issues of data loss, and speed will be efficient as well perfomance-wise. Try sending these packets using parallel processing.

If you're using node, try using lodash functions or bluebird functions in order to achieve what you want. This will also highly improve file send/receive performance.

Also use `atob()` to convert it back to an image.